# How can we validate radiobuttonlist inside Datalist based on Item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to validate all Approve Item on Button click not N/A or Reject.Please suggest me how can I achive this task. Pls see the image.

```
    int sum = 0;
   foreach    (DataListItem item in dtLstRejection.Items)
    {
   RadioButtonList rdlReasoncodeType ((RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rdlReasonType"));
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbldlmsg = (Label)item.FindControl("lbldlmsg");

        {
            if (rdlReasoncodeType.SelectedIndex == 0|| rdlReasoncodeType1.SelectedIndex== -1)
            {
                if (rdlReasoncodeType1.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                     if (sum == 0)
                        {
                  lbldlmsg.Text = "*Approve fields are mandatory to check";

     return;                          }}}}
                       else
            {

                sum++;
                lbldlmsg.Text = "";
                   }
            lbldlmsg.Text = "";
            }}
```

[image]

Comment: can you clarify exactly which buttons need to be checked?

Comment: Please crop your image...

Comment: I have one update button. When click on update  it should be mandatory to check Approved and For Reject and N/A validation should not work. Note: All data are binding from database.